# How do I X forward a Windows application to a Linux system using ssh?

Tags: x11, x11-forwarding

Ok, so if I have two Linux Machines (A and B) and I have a program on one, and want to run it on be I do:

- user@LinuxA:~$ ssh -X LinuxB
- user@LinuxB:~$ programName

(Displays on LinuxA machine)

---

Ok same thing, WindowsA LinuxB (Program on Linux)

1. Start Xming X Server on Windows
2. Run Putty, use x11 port forward with :0.0
3. After connect to LinuxB, run program, it loads in Windows!

---

Now here is the question,  WindowsA LinuxB, (Program on Windows)

Run Windows Program On Linux, using a windows resources.

How to make it work?  BTW, I know it can because years ago, I read a white paper on it, but never actually tested it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with x11 (indeed, the Windows application is not running under X11). However, a similar result may be achieved using the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). `rdesktop` is a Linux client implementing RDP.

After installing redesktop (`sudo apt-get install rdesktop`), tunnel through SSH if the machine is not local and forward port 3389, launch an application through rdesktop by specifying the credentials, host and program to start.  (See `man rdesktop` for more information.)

On the Windows machine install SeamlessRDP (see http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/ and the -A option to rdesktop)

On Linux machine:

`ssh -L 3389:localhost:3389 user@windowsHost #Forward port 3398 if needed`

`rdesktop -u user -d domain -A -s seamlessrdpshell notepad.exe -f windowsHost/localhost` #execute notepad

Launching without `-s argument` will give you a full interactive session similar to VNC, which would be a solution to achieve full remote control.

Comment: Thanks, but rdesktop pushes the entire desktop accross, and is mirrored on the actual machine.  If 3 people call firefox, they need to see their own version, not the same version everyone else is seeing.

Security isn't a major concern because this will be within a fire walled trusted network.

Comment: Whether it is mirrored or not depends on your version of Windows. I don't use the OS, but I think you need a 'server' version to not have sessions mirrored. I don't have a machine to test with any more, but long ago it was possible to only get the program window (just like X forwarding) by specifying the program as an argument in launch. MS might have changed this since I last used it.

Comment: see also the -A option for rdesktop (
`-A Enable  SeamlessRDP. In this mode, rdesktop creates a X11 window for each window on the server side. This mode requires the SeamlessRDP   server   side   component,  which  is  available  from http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/.  When using this option, you should specify a startup shell which launches the desired application through SeamlessRDP.

Example: rdesktop -A -s 'seamlessrdpshell notepad'.`
)

Comment: Thanks guys, I will have to try this out.  I have a windows server for free (go being a student), and I will see if I can get this working.